# Render Table <tr> tag based on condition in ReactJs within map loop

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table

I need to render `<tr>` start and close it, based on a condition:

```
{grid.map((item, index) => {
    return <React.Fragment key={index}>
        {item.x === 0 ? <tr/> : ""}
        <td id={`td_${item.x}_${item.y}`}>
            {item.name}
        </td>
    </React.Fragment>
})}
```

Above code rendering all `<td>` tag outside of `<tr>` tag, but I want all `<td>` in `<tr>` tag.
In this code, I want `<tr>` start when `item.x === 0` and need to render `</tr>` end in bottom this loop.

```
{grid.map((item, index) => {
    return <React.Fragment key={index}>
        {item.x === 0 ? <tr> : ""}
        <td id={`td_${item.x}_${item.y}`}>
            {item.name}
        </td>
        {item.x === 0 ? </tr> : ""}
    </React.Fragment>
})}
```

This code showing error in `jsx` syntax error.

Comment: Could you show us data you keep in `grid` array?

Answer (score 1):

React component trees aren't HTML strings, they're object trees. You need to have a `tr` object, provide it with a bunch of `td` children, and then switch to a new `tr` object and provide its children to it.

Ideally, change how you're storing `grid` so that it contains the rows, with child objects/arrays for the cells.

If you can't do that, you can do it on the fly:

```
const rows = [];
let children = [];
for (const item of grid) {
    if (grid.x === 0 && children.length) {
        rows.push(children);
        children = [];
    }
    children.push(item);
}
if (children.length) {
    rows.push(children);
}
```

Then to render:

```
{rows.map((children, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
        {children.map(item =>
            <td id={`td_${item.x}_${item.y}`}>
                {item.name}
             </td>
        )}
    </tr>
))}
```

You'll want to double-check that for minor typos, etc., but it's the fundamental idea: Build an array of rows, with arrays of cells inside.